# Showing 'print' commands from a module in python

Tags: python, module

I have two python scripts, lets call them  **file1.py** and **file2.py**, where I have different functions, let's say that **function11** and **function12** are in **file1**. I need to use those functions in my **file2.py** function : **function21**.

Now the problem is that I have a simple error, but I need to make a 'print' of the variables to see exactly why I have those errors. But the errors are sent from one of the functions of **file1** (that I am using from **file2**). And when I add some prints the results don't appear in the terminal.

Is there some way that I can do this ?

Comment: I can't understand the question. Perhaps you can elaborate, maybe with some code.

Comment: Maybe you should try debugging your code with a [debugger](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) instead of using simple prints to figure out the problem. That way you will see what exactly fails, and why certain prints do not appear. That being said, unless you change it explicitely, all prints should go to the same output.

Comment: Sounds like you need to factor out some code into a module that both share.

Comment: You might try using try/except clauses around the problematic areas in your code. In your except clause for the problematic function in file1, you can pass the variable values to file2 instead of the results of the function and print them from there. I'm afraid I can't offer much more advice without having some idea of what what your code looks like. (You can also use a debugger, as others have mentioned.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of what your script looks like, but you might try something like this (if you are not merely looking for a debugger):

file1.py

```
def function11(arg1, arg2):
    try:
        # try something with arg1, arg2 <---- throws error
        . . .
        # return something
    except:
        return arg1, arg2

def function12(arg3):
    # try something else
    . . .
    return something
```

file2.py

```
from file1 import *

def function21():
    try:
        # the following function should normally throw an error, but you have to be sure 
        # the result arg1, arg2 from function11 (in file1) still throws
        # an error and does not look like the expected result
        f = function11(arg1, arg2) 
        . . .
        return something
    except:     # <---- if function imported from file1.py throws error, you want to print variables instead.
        print arg1, arg2
```